# Insert occasionally missing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am running below query, sometimes these query skip few records to insert into `newordersholdentry` and didn't get any error.

but if run same query again after finding it is missed some records for order, it will insert all.

Please let me know what could be the reason.

```
INSERT INTO newordersholdentry
(itemid, 
 lookupcode, 
 description, 
 gamacode, 
 ordered, 
 IsForceItem, 
 Scanned, 
 Location, 
 SortOrder
)
       SELECT ID, 
              ItemLookupCode, 
              Description, 
              GamaCode, 
              SUM(Qty) AS Qty, 
              ForceItem, 
              0 AS Scanned, 
              SubDescription1, 
              Sortorder
       FROM
       (
           SELECT Item.ID, 
                  Item.ItemLookupCode, 
                  Item.Description, 
                  NewOrderItems.GamaCode, 
                  NewOrderItems.Qty, 
                  Item.SubDescription1, 
                  Item.Binlocation, 
                  ISNULL(
           (
               SELECT TOP (1) SortSno
               FROM NewOrderPickPackSorting
               WHERE(Bin = LEFT(Item.SubDescription1, 3))
           ), 99999) AS Expr1, 
                  0 AS ForceItem, 
                  p.sortorder
           FROM NewOrderItems(NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN Item(NOLOCK) ON NewOrderItems.GamaCode = Item.SubDescription2
                LEFT OUTER JOIN pickpath(NOLOCK) p ON concat(RTRIM(p.aisle), '-', p.section) = UPPER(LEFT(item.subdescription1, 6))
           WHERE(NewOrderItems.Discontinue = 0)
                AND (NewOrderItems.OrderID = 123456)
       ) AS t
        Group by ID
        , ItemLookupcode
        , Description
        , GAMACODE
        , ForceItem 
        , Expr1
        , BinLocation
        , SubDescription1
        , sortorder
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `nolock` for an insert statement as the results are unpredictable. Remove that and see if you still get the problem.

Comment: In addition, NOLOCK has been replaced by READUNCOMMITTED which makes more sense. If you get too many deadlocks, first thing should be to try reducing the request consumption. 
First, try to store your datas, doing the RTRIM and UPPER before the insertion.
Second, if you often compare the first chars (LEFT), you should store them in a separated column.
Same for the concat part.
All of this would help making your request SARGable (meaning it will use the indexes).